# I need to create a folder name 'Properties' in visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

How to create a folder name properties in visual studio.
Actually I need a website like 
Mysite.com/properties/Webpage.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the `csproj` using notepad or your favourite text editor. Look for the following line and replace Properties with something else.

```
<AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
```

Also, you will find something like these at the end of the project file:

```
<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
<AppDesigner Include="Properties\" />
```

Replace these occurrences of Properties, too. After saving these changes, rename the Properties folder in Explorer or your favourite file manager.

Do not forget to reopen the solution. Hopefully you can create a regular folder called Properties after all these.